# Maven is not launching the browser for selenium

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, junit, maven-2

I am doing a basic test in Selenium and I want it to execute from maven I am not getting any error but browser is not launched.and in TESTS section I get

```
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

my src/Test/java/Test.java is

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:/Users/swkv8851/Downloads/geckodriver-v0.15.0-win32/geckodriver.exe");

 Open open=new Open();
 open.Opengmail();
}
}
```

and my src/main/java.Open.java is:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class Open {

    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

public void Opengmail() throws Exception{   

driver.get("http://google.com");

driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.findElement(By.name("Email")).sendKeys ("somevalues");
String st=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='need-help']")).getText();
System.out.println(st);
Assert.assertEquals("Find my account", st);
driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.name("Passwd")).sendKeys ("some string");
driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
}

}
```

MY POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SeleniumTestWithMaven</groupId>
  <artifactId>SeleniumTestWithMaven</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SeleniumTestWithMaven</name>

  <dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

OUTPUT of execution:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SeleniumTestWithMaven 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ SeleniumTestWithMaven ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ SeleniumTestWithMaven ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ SeleniumTestWithMaven ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ SeleniumTestWithMaven ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ SeleniumTestWithMaven ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Personal\learn_selenium\workspace\SeleniumTestWithMaven\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.294 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-04T16:23:45+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/114M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

how can I my invoke my browser and perform test.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Version >3.0 requires GeckoDriver to run Firefox found @ https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Answer (score 0):

There is no test in your code (no @Test annotation)
You need something like this :

```
public class Test {

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:/Users/swkv8851/Downloads/geckodriver-v0.15.0-win32/geckodriver.exe");

        Open open=new Open();
        open.Opengmail();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my code .now I am getting error related to gecko driver but I have it in my code. previuosly it was not giving error.
My updated code is:

Error is:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property;


  

      
    @Test
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:/Users/swkv8851/Downloads/geckodriver-v0.15.0-win32/geckodriver.exe");

        Open open=new Open(driver);
        open.Opengmail();
    }
}

Comment: Please, can you update your question with the new code (keep the old code and add the new one)? Your @Test method can't be static and can't have any arguments